# How can I find nearest point in a time series data

Tags: algorithm, math

I need to calculate the nearest dataPoint in a time series chart from a specific point in a chart

I obviously cannot use d=sqrt(x*x+y*y) as my x axis is in time series, hence it wont make sense to have an equation where I am adding distance and time together (x,y need to have same units). Moreover visually it may seem right, but it still depends upon the scale of the x axis.

So what best logic can I use to find the nearest point?

I can think of using a quadratic form of x (i.e. time) so as that my final function can ne f(x*x,y), but then it is just a subjective equation.

Does anyone have a better and more logical approach to this. If there is an intuitive logical approach I will love it. And if there is a complicated model I would still like to know about it and explore it.

Thanks

**EDIT**

TO give background: I am polling people to predict where the stock price will be in April(they have to mention exact date when the expect price to be there) ... How do I measure their performance?

Comment: Exactly my point. Interpretations to the term "near"  will depend upon the solution. I am asking people to predict where the stock price will bet in next 30 to 4o days... How do I measure their performance?

Comment: Yes. That will be the simplest way. Just a clarity - the ones who guess the price need to tell me exact date that they expect the price to be there... lets say 18th April price will touch 90 $. Thereafter I need to run my algo to find how close they were. So absolute price difference wont be good enough because if price were 90 $ on 1st April, then the above mentioned person will win as compared to another guy who predicted price to be 91 $ on 18th April. It seems a tad unfair to the second guy.

Answer (score 0):

One intuitive way is by calculating the average absolute change per day.
i.e.
Sum of Absolute changes every day from previous day / Total number of days in series.

Thereafter I can translate each day in terms of prices i.e. the average price change per day.

Thus if average absolute change per day is lets say 2, then a price that is 10 days away can be said to be 20 price points away.

Thereafter I can calculate the distance based on sqrt(x*x+y*y) formula.

This can be fine tuned by using a bell curve (std dev and mean) rather than just mean of absolute change per day. But then it will make solution more ocmplicated.